# Index of element in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, indexof

In Python we can get the index of a value in an array by using `.index()`.

But with a NumPy array, when I try to do:

```
decoding.index(i)
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

How could I do this on a NumPy array?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use `np.where` to get the indices where a given condition is `True`.

Examples:

For a 2D `np.ndarray` called `a`:

```
i, j = np.where(a == value) # when comparing arrays of integers

i, j = np.where(np.isclose(a, value)) # when comparing floating-point arrays
```

For a 1D array:

```
i, = np.where(a == value) # integers

i, = np.where(np.isclose(a, value)) # floating-point
```

Note that this also works for conditions like `>=`, `<=`, `!=` and so forth...

You can also create a subclass of `np.ndarray` with an `index()` method:

```
class myarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array(*args, **kwargs).view(myarray)
    def index(self, value):
        return np.where(self == value)
```

Testing:

```
a = myarray([1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,4,4,4])
a.index(4)
#(array([ 3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10]),)
```

Comment: Why have the commata after the variable names in the 1D cases? Just in case the input is bad?

Comment: @BUFU, that's because the output of `np.where` is always a `tuple`. If I used `i = np.where(...)`, my variable `i` would be a `tuple` object

Answer (score 33):

**You can convert a numpy array to list and get its index .**

for example:

```
tmp = [1,2,3,4,5] #python list
a = numpy.array(tmp) #numpy array
i = list(a).index(2) # i will return index of 2, which is 1
```

this is just what you wanted.

Answer (score 18):

I'm torn between these two ways of implementing an index of a NumPy array:

```
idx = list(classes).index(var)
idx = np.where(classes == var)
```

Both take the same number of characters, but the first method returns an `int` instead of a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: idx = list(classes).index(var) <----- This is awesome!

Answer (score 10):

This problem can be solved efficiently using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/arraysetops.py#L115) library (disclaimer: I am its author); which was created to address problems of this type. npi.indices can be viewed as an n-dimensional generalisation of list.index. It will act on nd-arrays (along a specified axis); and also will look up multiple entries in a vectorized manner as opposed to a single item at a time.

```
a = np.random.rand(50, 60, 70)
i = np.random.randint(0, len(a), 40)
b = a[i]

import numpy_indexed as npi
assert all(i == npi.indices(a, b))
```

This solution has better time complexity (n log n at worst) than any of the previously posted answers, and is fully vectorized.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `numpy.nonzero()`, or the `nonzero()` method of an array

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2,4],
          [6,2]])
index= np.nonzero(A>1)
       OR
(A>1).nonzero()
```

**Output**:

```
(array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))
```

First array in output depicts the **row index** and second array depicts the corresponding **column index**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the indexes, the best choice is np.argsort(a)

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
sorted_idx = np.argsort(a)
```