# Array of indizes of unique values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I start with an array `a` containing `N` unique values (`product(a.shape) >= N`).
I need to find the array `b` that has the index `0 .. N-1` from the (sorted) list of unique values in `a` at the positions of the respective elements in `a`.

As an example

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.choice([0.1,1.3,7,9.4], size=(4,3))
print a
```

prints `a` as

```
[[ 7.   9.4  0.1]
 [ 7.   7.   9.4]
 [ 0.1  0.1  7. ]
 [ 1.3  7.   7. ]]
```

The unique values are `[0.1, 1.3, 7.0, 9.4]`, so the required outcome `b` would be

```
[[2 3 0]
 [2 2 3]
 [0 0 2]
 [1 2 2]]
```

(e.g. the value at `a[0,0]` is `7.`; `7.` has the index `2`; thus `b[0,0] == 2`.)

Since [numpy does not have an index function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079029/index-of-element-in-numpy-array),
I could do this using a loop. Either looping over the input array, like this:

```
u = np.unique(a).tolist()
af = a.flatten()
b = np.empty(len(af), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(af)):
    b[i] = u.index(af[i])
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
print b
```

or looping over the unique values as follows:

```
u = np.unique(a)
b = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=int)
for i in range(len(u)):
    b[np.where(a == u[i])] = i
print b
```

I suppose that the second way of looping over the unique values is already more efficient than the first in cases where not all values in `a` are distinct; but still, it involves this loop and is rather inefficient compared to inplace operations.

So my question is: What is the most efficient way of obtaining the array `b` filled with the indizes of the unique values of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional argument `return_inverse` -

```
np.unique(a, return_inverse=1)[1].reshape(a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [308]: a
Out[308]: 
array([[ 7. ,  9.4,  0.1],
       [ 7. ,  7. ,  9.4],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  7. ],
       [ 1.3,  7. ,  7. ]])

In [309]: np.unique(a, return_inverse=1)[1].reshape(a.shape)
Out[309]: 
array([[2, 3, 0],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 2]])
```

Going through the [source code of `np.unique`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L192-L227) that looks pretty efficient to me, but still pruning out the un-necessary parts, we would end up with another solution, like so -

```
def unique_return_inverse(a):
    ar = a.flatten()     
    perm = ar.argsort()
    aux = ar[perm]
    flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))
    iflag = np.cumsum(flag) - 1
    inv_idx = np.empty(ar.shape, dtype=np.intp)
    inv_idx[perm] = iflag
    return inv_idx
```

Timings -

```
In [444]: a= np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000,400))

In [445]: np.allclose( np.unique(a, return_inverse=1)[1],unique_return_inverse(a))
Out[445]: True

In [446]: %timeit np.unique(a, return_inverse=1)[1]
10 loops, best of 3: 30.4 ms per loop

In [447]: %timeit unique_return_inverse(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ms per loop
```

Not a great deal of improvement there over the built-in.

Comment: Wow, this is already a very good candidate for being accepted. However it returns (creates) two arrays of the size of `a`, right? So there might be a more efficient solution in terms of memory?!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Added another one for a very very marginal improvement.