# finding index/location of value in 1D NumPy array (with identical values)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I want to find the index/location of a randomly chosen number in a 1D NumPy array within the array itself, but when I try the following:

```
a = np.array(np.linspace(1,10,10))
b = np.random.choice(a)
print(a.index(b))
```

It doesn't work and can't figure out where the problem is. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: how do you only index the randomly chosen value if the values in the NumPy array are identical, for example:

```
a = np.array(np.linspace(10,10,10))
```

Comment: I am not sure index function works with arrays, try this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079029/index-of-element-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `where` function as already answer here [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(np.linspace(1,10,10))
b = np.random.choice(a)
print(np.where(a==b))
```

If the value are the same, `where` return multiple index, example:

```
a = np.array(np.linspace(10,10,10))
print(np.where(a==10))

>>> (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
```

Here all index are turned because 10 is in all position.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Another question if i'm not bothering you: what if the values in the array are identical? Because then this method doesn't work properly unfortunately.

Comment: I see. Thanks!  But is it possible to only index the randomly chosen value in the NumPy array containing identical values? (again, sorry for bothering you)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I am trying to index the location of a randomly chosen value within a NumPy array containing identical values.

Comment: Well, the code I write will also work for a random value.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your desired output:

```
np.where(a==b)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's [where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function does what you want, as described in other answers. If you only have 1D arrays and you only want the index of the first element in `a` which equals `b`, `where()` is both clunky and inefficient. Instead, you may use

```
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)  # Hint: the np.array() is superfluous
b = np.random.choice(a)
index = next(i for i, el in enumerate(a) if el == b)
print(index, a[index])
```