# How to find an index of a permutation of an array with package "numpy_indexed"?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I've search on author's [github](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/arraysetops.py#L115) and [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-indexed/), but could not find any example of using this package. The author mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536728/7357673) that this package *is fully vectorized*. In below example, I would like to find the index of each element of `Y` in `X`. Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
X = np.array([0, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2])
Y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

My intended result is `[0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Not very clear on the intended result or how's numpy_indexed involved. Seems like this could solve it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678543/. Does it?

Comment: @Divakar My intended result is `[0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]`. When I use the function in your answer `np.nonzero(np.in1d(X, Y))[0]`, I got `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)`, which is not as expected. Could you please suggest a fix?

Comment: Use `sorter` solution. For specific scenario of positive numbers, there are other answers too.

Comment: My array is very large and contains only a permutation of `0, 1, ..., n`. This procedure is repeated several times, please suggest me an approach this is efficient @Divakar.

Comment: As I said check out other answers too in that thread (Q&A).

Comment: Ah I miss understand your comment @Divakar. I though you mean other answers (in other places). Now I got you meant other answers in the same linked question.